# php webservice print value

Tags: php, web-services, soap-client

I have this webservice snippet and i want to print the actual value returned.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx?WSDL");// Gets the webservice
$Converte =  $client->ConversionRate (array("FromCurrency"=>"USD","ToCurrency"=>"ILS")); //calls the converter
```

Now i want to get the value (when i do this in the webservice itself, i get xml and value of 3.94 ~, but when i try lets say print_r($converte) I get

```
stdClass Object ( [ConversionRateResult] => 3.94 )
```

Comment: `print $Converte->ConversionRateResult` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print_r` is printing out the properties of the object being returned to you by the web service.  From what it looks like, there is just one property in the response, `ConversionRateResult`

A `stdClass` is an object whose properties can be accessed with the object operator `->`

`echo $Converte->ConversionRateResult;`

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($converte["ConversionRateResult"]);
```

Is this what you're looking for? if so i'll edit this with more information.